# django runserver command is not starting the server

Tags: django

I'm running Django and I can't figure out why it's coming out like that.
It turns out that Python and Django are installed.

input : python manage.py runserver

output : Python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys
def main():
"""Run administrative tasks."""
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'cmapsite.settings')
try:
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
except ImportError as exc:
    raise ImportError(
        "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
        "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
        "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
    ) from exc
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Comment: Instead of giving a picture while removing personal details, copy, edit and put the output in your question, also can you show the contents of `manage.py`

Comment: Please show the contents of `manage.py`

Comment: In your cmd or terminal just type `python` what is the output?

Comment: microsoft store opens

Comment: But when I type py, Python 3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:43:08) [MSC v.1926 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Comment: try running `py manage.py runserver` then. Also are you using a virtual environment if so make sure to activate it before running anything and in this case `python manage.py runserver` will work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you activate your Virtual Environment in CMD terminal ?

If No then First Activate your Virtual Environment, It may be a reason of not starting Server.

If you already created the virtual environment then which is the error that you keep getting ? Upload the Error.

Comment: Thank You Very Much. I had the same problem. Then i found your Answer